# dojo ContentPane OnMouseOut can"t work well

Tags: datagrid, dojo, contentpane

The code is like below

the problem is that sometimes the contentPane with html content cannot close when the mouse move out of the cell filled with name field of the grid.

```
var myContentPane;

            grid.on("CellMouseOver",function(evt){

                var cell=evt.cell;

                rowData=grid.getItem(evt.rowIndex);

                if(cell.field=="name"){
                    require([
                             "dojox/layout/ContentPane",
                             "dijit/popup"
                         ], function(ContentPane, popup){

                                if(myContentPane){
                                    popup.close(myContentPane);
                                }

                                myContentPane = new ContentPane({
                                    style: "width:300px;background:#dddddd",
                                    content:"html content string has some links in it",
                                    onMouseLeave:function(){
                                       popup.close(myContentPane);
                                    }
                                });

                                popup.open({
                                     popup: myContentPane,
                                     around: dom.byId(rowData.name),
                                });
                         });

              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to connect the OnMouseOut like this.

First setup your Contentpane :

```
myContentPane = new ContentPane({
                id:"myContentPane",
                style: "width:300px;background:#dddddd",
                content:"<p style='text-align:center;'>"....
                }, "MyContentPaneDiv");
```

The connect the onMouseOut:

```
      myContentPane.on("MouseOut",function(){
               //do what you want to do;
       });
```

Think this should help u out.

Regards

Comment: oh,thanks.I have used the method you suggested, but there is still the same problem.May you give another suggestion, thanks very much!

Comment: I would guess the problem is the way you attache your ContentPane - can you add some more Code and discribe what you want to do with the Popup. Should the ContentPane is toggled in and Out, than you can use the dojo toggler - Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274282/dojo-toggle-hide-and-show-divs

Comment: hi.thanks,I have update the description of the problem.i thought the toggle is not fit my requirement.i want when mouse move over the cell filled with name field the contentPane with personal detail information and some links show;when mouse move out of the cell the contentPane disappear.the problem is sometimes it cannot disapper,especially when i move over to the cell then move to other cells in same row of the grid.and i also have tried to use the cellMouseOut,rowMouseOut and MouseOut event in the grid to remove,but the contentPane becomes flash show or can't click links in the contentPane.